# $f(x) = x^TMx$, using Lagrange multipliers to prove SVD decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I'm reading the [existence proof of singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Existence_proofs).

It considers $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^TMx$. It talks about the gradient of $f$ and make it equal to a multiple of the gradient of $x^tx$. I suppose that it's because the constraint is the unit sphere, so that's why it made $x^tx = x_1^2 + \cdots x_n^2$, right?

I'm trying to understand this so I took $f$ with a generic matrix $M$

$$f(x) =\begin{bmatrix} 
    x_1  & \cdots & x_n 
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \\
    a_{n1} &        & a_{nn} 
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
    x_1  \\
    \vdots  \\
    x_n  
    \end{bmatrix} = \\ x_1(a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n) + \\x_2 (a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \cdots + a_{2n}x_n) + \\
\cdots  + \\x_n(a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2 + \cdots + a_{nn}x_n)$$

Taking the partials to construct the gradient vector, I can see that I'll end up with:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
    2a_{11}x_1 + a_{21} + \cdots a_{n1}  \\
    a_{12} + 2a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_{n2} \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{1n} + a_{2n}\cdots + 2a_{nn}x_n\\  
    \end{bmatrix} $$

Now, I need to equal this with $\lambda$ gradient of $x^tx$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
    2x_1  \\
    2x_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    2x_n\\  
    \end{bmatrix}$$

so:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
    2a_{11}x_1 + a_{21} + \cdots a_{n1}  \\
    a_{12} + 2a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_{n2} \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{1n} + a_{2n}\cdots + 2a_{nn}x_n\\  
    \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 
    2x_1  \\
    2x_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    2x_n\\  
    \end{bmatrix} $$

As an example, the first line becomes:

$2a_{11}x_1 + a_{21} + \cdots a_{n1} = \lambda 2x_1 \implies \lambda 2x_1 -2a_{11}x_1 =  a_{21} + \cdots a_{n1}\implies x_1(2\lambda - 2a_{11}) =  a_{21} + \cdots a_{n1}$

What should I do now? It says that I should end up with $Mu = \lambda u$

Also, is there a more elegant way of calculating the gradients or it's just all this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake computing the gradient of

$$\\ x_1(a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n) + \\x_2 (a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + \cdots + a_{2n}x_n) + \\
\vdots   \\x_n(a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2 + \cdots + a_{nn}x_n)$$
For example, the partial derivative of this with respect to $x_1$ is
$$
\underbrace{2a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\dots+a_{1n}x_n}_{\text{first row}}+\underbrace{a_{21}x_2+\dots+a_{n1}x_n}_{\text{first term of remaining rows}}
$$
which you can recognize as the first entry of $(M+M^\top)x$. Therefore, the Lagrange multiplier equation becomes 
$$
(M+M^\top)x=2\lambda x
$$
If you are further given that $M$ is symmetric, this implies $Mx=\lambda x$.